# how to hide unchecked box using jquery or php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox, show-hide

I have a select option, I have a written function when I click a particular option it will fetch values related to that option and this particular value will be checked using the checkbox and other values will be unchecked.

I need to hide those unchecked values or else I need to keep unchecked values below the toggle button!! I am stuck right now!

```
<input type="checkbox" class="value" name="value[]" id="value<?=$i?>" value="<?=$brow["process"]?>" data-process-name="<?=$brow["process_name"]?>"/>&nbsp; <?=$brow["process_name"]?>
```

also, I am getting checkbox value as an array!

help me to solve this!

I added screenshot of checkbox where I get unchecked values below the checked values.

JS:

```
         if(jsonProcessArr.length > 0){
                        $(".proces_name_value").each(function(){
                            if($.trim(this.value) != ""){
                                if ($.inArray(this.value, jsonProcessArr) != -1){
                                    $(this).prop("checked",true);
                                }
                                else{
                                    $(this).prop("checked",false);
                                        
                                
                                } // here I check values from json and if there is the value inside json it will check otherwise uncheck//
```

after I receive checked and unchecked values together!!

mycode:

```
<div class="row form-group ">
            
                            
                    <?php
                    $pquery = "SELECT distinct(process_name),process_nid FROM bi_process_info   WHERE status=true"; 
                    $presult = mysqli_query($conn, $pquery); 
                    $i =1;
                    while ($brow = mysqli_fetch_array($presult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
                    {
                        ?>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 form-group">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="proces_name_value process_name" name="process_value[]" id="process_value<?=$i?>" value="<?=$brow["process_nid"]?>" data-process-name="<?=$brow["process_name"]?>">&nbsp; <?=$brow["process_name"]?></input>
                        </div>
                        
                        
                    <?php
                        $i++;
                    } ?>
                                
                    
                </div>
```

already i added my ajaxcall code !! so after that ajax call i added function where it hides unchecked checkbox :

```
    function uncheck(){
    $('.process_name').each(function(){
    $t_this= $(this);
    if($t_this.is(':checked')){
        
        $t_this.show();
    }
    else
    {
    $t_this.parent().hide(); // this hides my element but when i click another option i hiding values but it hided values that are already hided
i dont want to do that!! 
is there any way to refresh the hided elements?

    
    }
});

}
```

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: please add some HTML and js script what you tried and where you stuck.

Comment: @Neeraj I added!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uvYzW/2/  try this may help you.

Comment: @Neeraj i tried your method!  but its seem to be i have to check to hide those elements! but my concept is "i am getting values checked and unchecked through function" and i need to hide those unchecked elements after that function!

Comment: add this line  $('input.yourcheckboxsclassName:not(:checked)').hide();

Comment: @Neeraj hmm.. it hided all checked and uncheckbox now! what to do?

Comment: put this it's work $('.contact_no').each(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
            $this.show()
        } else {
            $this.hide()
        }
    });

Comment: @Neeraj what should i put in the place of $('.contact_no')? should i have to put checkbox classname there?

Comment: hmm yes it works now! but this function is applying only for checkbox!  i also want to hide checkbox with label! like checkbox contains name! i attached screenshot for your reference... @Neeraj

Comment: @Neeraj Hey dude ! i tried your last method it works fine and also i added line to hide the label also like "else{ $t_this.parent().hide();} " it does hide the element !! but now it hiding all element when i select my option! when i select more and more , its hiding all element!! but i dont want to hide like that...I  added screenshot for your reference...

Comment: it's difficult to help you without knowing your HTML structure.

Comment: @Neeraj i updated the code! now you can have a look and i hope this will help me. .thanks for mentioning previous method..

Comment: where is your label html?

Comment: @Neeraj actually i am getting value through checkbox itself!! before </input> i get value!! <input type="checkbox" class="proces_name_value process_name" name="process_value[]" id="process_value<?=$i?>" value="<?=$brow["process_nid"]?>" data-process-name="<?=$brow["process_name"]?>">&nbsp; **<?=$brow["process_name"]?>** </input>

Comment: var $myLabel = $(this).next('label');  for find label and for hide it  $myLabel.hide();

Comment: @Neeraj  what does $mycheckbox  contains here ?

Comment: $myLabel = $t_this.next('label') try this $myLabel.hide();

Comment: @Neeraj hmm this doesn't work!! its not hiding at all... is there anyway to destroy the function after it performs hide function??

Comment: sorry, very difficult to help without knowing or seeing code.

Comment: @Neeraj hmm i already provided code that i am working..thanks anyway :)

Comment: You need to learn about the jquery function like how to get elements using jquery so you can solve this.

Comment: @ hey dude! i solved it ! i just made some correction that you  previously  mentioned code like $t_this.parent().show(); now its working perfect!!

Comment: ohk great!! ..keep learning.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you're getting the value back as an array because the name="value[]" contains '[]'. Drop the braces and it will return as a single value. Second, all child checkboxes that you want to hide should be in the nested html or have dedicated classes to handle this.

I would recommend the below (Note: the children could be an array if you desire)

```
<div>
    <div>
        <input type='checkbox' class='someCheckbox' name='value'>

        <div class='children'>
           <input  type='checkbox' name='childValue1'>
           <input  type='checkbox' name='childValue2'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type='checkbox' class='someCheckbox' name='value'>

        <div class='children'>
           <input  type='checkbox' name='childValue3'>
           <input  type='checkbox' name='childValue4'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
jQuery(document).on('change','.someCheckbox',function(event){
let checkbox = jQuery(event.target);
   if(checkbox.prop('checked')){
       checkbox.siblings('.children').show();
   }else{
       checkbox.siblings('.children').hide();
   }
})

</script>
```